# Place cells certain distance apart using Design compiler (DC)

Tags: synthesis, rtl, tcl

So as an example for self-learning, I am trying to place two Flip Flops (FFs) at a certain distance apart.

Except for these two FFs which must be at a certain distance apart, other cells might occupy any place (in between, etc.).

The two FFs are "`FSM_reg_3_`" and "`FSM_reg_4_`" in the following example.

In order to achieve that I wrote this [TCL code](https://ibb.co/VJ13ghQ) using `create_rp_group`, but getting this **unknown command** error shown in the DC.

Does anyone know the reason?

Comment: You should give more context about the compiler product and the target you are working with

Comment: It's ASIC and I have the verilog design as an input to Design compiler which then links to the tech library say 90 nm ...then I have the synthesized design ..Does that answer the question?

Comment: Every design tool has a forum. You can post there for better responses as this is tool-specific and nothing to do with EESE

Comment: Add information to the question, don't dribble it out in comments.

Comment: @MituRaj Where do I post for my kind of problem..any idea?